# how to search in an array with php

Tags: php, arrays

im trying to make a search function for my website, but i cannot get it to work.
here is my code:

```
$search_string = "html documentation";
$search_string = explode(' ', $search_string);

$array = "


  Array (
    [0] => Array (
      [0] => 404
      [1] => notfound
      [2] => error
    )

    [1] => Array (
      [0] => 403
      [1] => forbidden
      [2] => error
    )

    [2] => Array (
      [0] => home
    )

    [3] => Array (
      [0] => hcjp
      [1] => html
      [2] => css
      [3] => js
      [4] => php
      [5] => learning
      [6] => documentation
    )

    [4] => Array (
      [0] => about
    )

    [5] => Array (
      [0] => search
      [1] => search on no conditions
    )

    [6] => Array (
      [0] => search
      [1] => search on label
    )
  )

";

$search_result = in_array($search_string, $array);
print_r($search_result);
```

i am not getting any output, my goal is to get some sort of path like: [3], so that i know that:

```
$search_result[3]
```

contains info the user requested.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it might be to loop the arrays in `$array` and use [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php). If there is a match then return the `$key` from `$array`

```
foreach ($array as $key => $a) {
    if (count(array_intersect($a, $search_string)) > 0) {
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/fXU3Y)

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote has some issues.

The [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function returns an array of strings and even though the `in_array` can support an array as needle, the way you have constructed your `$array` make it -if not impossible- really hard to work. Also, your `$array` is an array of arrays and not a single-dimension one.

The following solution can do what you want but bear in mind that it won't be the most efficient one if your `$array` ever consists of hundreds of sub-arrays.

```
// get search term
$search_string = "html documentation";
// explode in on space => ['html', 'documentation']
$search_strings = explode(' ', $search_string);


$array = [
    ['404', 'not found', 'error'],
    ['403', 'forbidden', 'error'],
    ['home'],
    ['hcop', 'html', 'css', 'js', 'php', 'learning', 'documentation'],
    ...
];

// set an array that will hold your search related info
$search_result = [];

// go through the search terms i.e. html, documentation
foreach($search_strings as $term) {

    // loop through your array, $key will be the index of the sub-array and $value the sub-array itself
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {

        // if the term is in the sub-array, set the $term as key and the $key as the value
        if (in_array($term, $value)) {
            $search_result[$term] = $key;
        }

    }

}

// Array ( [html] => 3 [documentation] => 3 )
print_r($search_result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_grep and see if the count of the match is the same as the count of the input word count.

```
$search_string = "html documentation";
$searchArr = explode(" ", $search_string);
$search_strings = "/" . implode('|', $searchArr) ."/";


$array = [
    ['404', 'not found', 'error'],
    ['403', 'forbidden', 'error'],
    ['home'],
    ['hcop', 'html', 'css', 'js', 'php', 'learning', 'documentation']
];
foreach($array as $key => $arr){
    $out = preg_grep($search_strings, $arr);
    if(count($out) == count($searchArr)){
        echo "match in key $key!\n";
        var_dump($arr);
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/b0X5W